# A confusion about complex measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The 3.13 proposition from the book "Real Analysis" by Folland:

> Let $\nu$ be a complex measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$.

> a.$\left| \nu \left( E \right) \right|\le \left| \nu \right|\left( E \right) $ for all $E\in\mathcal{M}$.

> b.$\nu \leqslant \left| \nu \right|$,and $d\nu/d\lvert \nu\rvert$ has absolute value 1 $\lvert \nu \rvert-a.e.$

> c.$L^1(\nu)=L^1(\lvert \nu \rvert)$, and if $f\in L^1(\nu)$, then $\lvert \int f d\nu\rvert \leq \int \lvert f\rvert d\lvert \nu\rvert$.

The following is the proof of this book:

> Suppose $d\nu=f\mu$ as in the definition of $\lvert\nu\rvert$.Then
> $$
> \left| \nu \left( E \right) \right|=\left| \int_E{f}d\mu \right|\le \int_E{\left| f \right|d\mu}=\left| \nu \right|\left( E \right) 
> $$
> This proves (a) and shows that $\nu \ll \lvert \nu\rvert$.If $g=d\nu/d\lvert \nu\rvert$,then,we have$$
> fd\mu =d\nu =gd\left| \nu \right|=g\left| f \right|d\mu 
> $$
> so $g\lvert f\rvert =f$ $\mu$-a.e. and hence $\lvert \nu\rvert-a.e.$But clearly $\lvert f\rvert>0 \lvert \nu\rvert-a.e.$,whence $\lvert g\rvert=1 \lvert \nu\rvert-a.e.$
> Part (c) is left to the reader.

My **question** is that why "clearly $\lvert f\rvert>0 \lvert \nu\rvert$-a.e"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\{x: |f(x)|=0\}=\{x: f(x)=0\}$. For every measurable set $B \subseteq A$ we have $\nu (B)=\int_B fd\mu=0$. This implies that $|\nu|(A)=0$.